# how to select loop id in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

i have ids in my html tag example

```
<% @comment.each do |c|%>
<textarea id="comment-<%#{c.id} %>" name="commenter[comment]"></textarea>
<% end %>
```

if i have 3 comments in my @comments it will be like this

```
 <textarea id="comment-23 %>" name="commenter[comment]">
 </textarea>
 <textarea id="comment-27 %>" name="commenter[comment]">
 </textarea>
 <textarea id="comment-45 %>" name="commenter[comment]">
 </textarea>
```

how can javascript determine what id i select if i use click?

my button

```
<button id = <%="#{c.id}"%> onclick="click(this.id)">comment</button>
```

my js

```
function click(click_id)
{
alert(click_id);
}
```

this is my to do list 
first i want to alert my id in my comment button then
if my comment button is working i want to focus my textarea using the button

Comment: what javascript have you tried?

Comment: I mean, we don't know what you mean by `click`, how are you handling click in your javascript?

Comment: here you go mate i edit my post thanks for helping :*

Comment: i think you can add extra data attribute to the element and then use it to find the other values.

Comment: i am new in JS sir Milind can you give me an example thanks for the reply :*

Comment: it was working now thanks guys sorry for my interruption? my last question can i use link_to instead of button? can i put onclick in the link_to?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but, you don't need to do this: `<%="#{c.id}"%>`, you can just do this: `<%= c.id %>` Rails will deal with the character-coercion for you.

Comment: your right thanks Taryn

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as

```
<% @comment.each do |c|%>
<textarea data-id="<%= c.id %>" name="commenter[comment]"></textarea>
<% end %>
```

Now in you js file you can achieve it as

```
$("body").on("click", "[data-id]", function(event) {
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```